# How to schedule Jest tests to run hourly

Tags: jestjs

I'd like to auto run my jest tests hourly without any manual intervention.

Can I simply add something like:

```
jest test.js
```

to a shell script and run it via the cron?

Comment: You should https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html

Comment: thanks @Hackerman - yip I've seen the cli - just seems to be a real lack of practical examples of people running Jest in an automated way in the manner I'm describing - hence my question.

Comment: You can use those examples, and try with cron, npm-cron or with npm-schedule

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-javascript-cron-cron-jobs-cronjob-reactjs-scheduler-schedule-example-tutorial-25bcbe23bc6b

Comment: thanks @Hackerman - you steered me in the right direction - ended up doing something like this: */5 * * * * /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/jest --config=/path/to/my/tests/package.json /path/to/my/tests/test.js